# Algebra simplification involving power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I'm taking a statistics course and reading notes this equation :

$$
\frac{1-n}{2}(1-2t)^{\frac{1-n}{2}}(-2)
$$

is simplified to :

$$
(n-1)(1-2t)^{\frac{-1-n}{2}}
$$

Simplification I've calculated is result of multiplying

$$
\frac{1-n}{2}(1-2t)^{\frac{1-n}{2}} 
$$

by -2 :

$$
\frac{1-n}{2}(2+4t)^{\frac{1-n}{2}}
$$

How is more simpler version :

$$
(n-1)(1-2t)^{\frac{-1-n}{2}}
$$

arrived at ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just: $$\frac{1-n}{2}(1-2t)^{\frac{1-n}{2}}(-2)=\left((-2)\cdot\frac{1-n}{2}\right)(1-2t)^{\frac{1-n}{2}}=(n-1)(1-2t)^{\frac{1-n}{2}}.$$